# How can i directly access array from ` mapping(string => uint256[]) public _didToDealIndexes`?

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

I have mapping -
  `mapping(string => uint256[]) public _didToDealIndexes;`

and I am trying to access it like this -

```
 await deals._didToDealIndexes(
     "did1",
      ethers.BigNumber.from("0")
 )
```

and also tried this -

```
 await deals._didToDealIndexes(
     "did1",
      0
 )
```

But I am getting the error - `Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string`.

Comment: has the array already elements or is it initialized?, maybe add the relevant construct code or the AddDidToDealIndesxes method

Answer (score 0):

should not the function be called like this,

```
 await deals._didToDealIndexes(
     "did1"
 )[ethers.BigNumber.from("0")]
```

Comment: Apparently, _didToDealIndexes requires 2 args for which the 2nd arg should be of type BigNumberish

Comment: would be helpful if you paste your solidity code here

Comment: Actually its quite huge, even it's exceeding 24kb (a limit introduced in Spurious Dragon) which is making impossible to deploy the contract. Thats the reason am making the mapping as public instead of using function to return the array.